# Closest Pair Algorithm in Python: difficulty sorting by x and y coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to define a function that takes an array, consisted of points with x and y coordinates, as input. I need 2 outputs: one array that has the points sorted by their x coordinates and another array that has the points sorted by their y coordinate. I'm doing it in python. Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you already have and where you're stuck, and we can show you how to get unstuck. Without any details, the best I can do is point you to [Key Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) in the docs. You can write a key function, or just use `itemgetter` or `attrgetter` (depending on how you're representing points), as shown in the examples.

Comment: Meanwhile, why is this tagged `mergesort` and `algorithm`? Are you writing your own mergesort function instead of using Python's `sort` or `sorted`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your array looks like the following:

```
input = [(1,2), (3,4), ..., (x,y)]
```

You can use the `sorted` method (built-in) to accomplish list sorting:

```
x_sorted = sorted(input, key=lambda tup: tup[0])
y_sorted = sorted(input, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

Where the lambda will sort your variable by the first and second indices, respectively

Comment: Your explanation points to the `sort` method, but your example uses the `sorted` function.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the **[`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)**  function as the **[`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)** parameter to the **[`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)** function:

```
from operator import itemgetter

points = [(7,3), (2,1), (4,5), (9,0)]
sorted_by_x = sorted(points) # you can add the key parameter itemgetter(0) if you want
sorted_by_y = sorted(points, key=itemgetter(1))

print("Points List: {}".format(points))
print("Sorted by X Points List: {}".format(sorted_by_x))
print("Sorted by Y Points List: {}".format(sorted_by_y))
```

**Output:**

```
Points List: [(7, 3), (2, 1), (4, 5), (9, 0)]
Sorted by X Points List: [(2, 1), (4, 5), (7, 3), (9, 0)]
Sorted by Y Points List: [(9, 0), (2, 1), (7, 3), (4, 5)]
```